# GridView program providing ClassCastexception in logcat

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, classcastexception

I have an android program. That will get json from server and parse the images into a gridview. But now it will provide a ClassCastException in logcat while running it in emulator/device. I can't find out where is this error happening in my program, Please someone help me to fix this

**GridViewActivity.java**

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    private Utils utils;
    private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
    private GridView gridView;
    private int columnWidth;
    private String image_first[];
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context activityContext = GridViewActivity.this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        utils = new Utils();

        // Initilizing Grid View
        InitilizeGridLayout();

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
           if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&    conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                new HttpAsyncTask(activityContext).execute("http://vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv.com/Android_Test/index2.php"/*"http://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json"*/);
           } else {
               final AlertDialog.Builder myDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
               myDialogue.setTitle("Connection Error!");
               myDialogue.setMessage("This Application requires internet please check your connection settings..." );

               myDialogue.setCancelable(false);

               myDialogue.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
               {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       System.exit(0);
//                     Intent i = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
//                     activityContext.startActivity(i);                       
                   }
               });

               AlertDialog dialog = myDialogue.create();
               dialog.show();
           }
    }

    private void InitilizeGridLayout() {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                4, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth(this) - ((2 + 1) * padding)) /2);

        gridView.setNumColumns(2);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        //gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
            //  (int) padding);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }

    public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

     private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;

            inputStream.close();
            return result;

        }



    public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        public HttpAsyncTask(Context c) {
            // Store the activity context
           activityContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(activityContext); 
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait");
            pd.setMessage("Downloading images...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url =  GET(urls[0]);

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(url);

                JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("images");
                 image_first =new String[json.getJSONArray("images").length()];  //initializtion

                for(int i=0;i<json.getJSONArray("images").length();i++)
                {   
                    image_first[i] = (articles.getJSONObject(i).optString("image_first"));
                }   

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Connection Error");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Check your internet connection!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                GridViewActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });


                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                e.printStackTrace();

                }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No inrternet available");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Check your internet connection!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                GridViewActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });


                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();

                }
            return image_first;

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

            pd.dismiss();

            ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result));  
            // Gridview adapter
            adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, imagePaths,
                    (int) (columnWidth/1.2),getApplicationContext());

            // setting grid view adapter
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);





       }
    }

}
```

**GridViewImageAdapter.java**

```
    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int imageWidth;
    private Context _cntxt;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
            int imageWidth,Context cntxt) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._filePaths = filePaths;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        this._cntxt = cntxt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this._filePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
                imageWidth));

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(_cntxt);

        // whenever you want to load an image from url
        // call DisplayImage function
        // url - image url to load
        // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
        // image - ImageView 
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(_filePaths.get(position), imageView);

        // image view click listener
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

        return imageView;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        int _postion;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this._postion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", _postion);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("arraylist", _filePaths);
            _activity.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    Activity act;

    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        act.getWindow().openPanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, event);
    }

}
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    LinearLayout l;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.loader;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(url);

        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

       Bitmap c =   bitmap;
//memoryCache.get(url);
        if(c!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(c);
        else
        {
           // queuePhoto(url, imageView);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }

    }


    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {



        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

Bitmap bm = getBitmap(urls[0]);

return bm;

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {

            bitmap = b;





       }
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
06-06 03:07:03.170: D/AndroidRuntime(800): Shutting down VM
06-06 03:07:03.170: W/dalvikvm(800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1042)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-06 03:07:03.440: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that you used alreayd Gridview as your layout params but what you did is that you set the `setLayoutParams` method again to `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and thus catching the exception.

**solution:**

remove the `imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))`

**sample:**
change this

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
```

**to**

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thank you its working now but the imageview get streched